# Questions about golang importing jwt

Tags: go, import, jwt, grails-orm

```
package common

import (
     "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

type Claims struct {
   UserId uint
   jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

Above is my code.  Today, after using the gin and gorm framework normally, I created a new jwt.go file in the common package. When I run the main function, golang prompts an error (undefined: jwt) in the last line, but in the go.mod file, I am prompted that I have downloaded "github. com/dgrijalva/jwt-go".

I tried to get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go and `import go get - u github.com/golang-jwt/jwt` again, but neither of the two methods worked

Comment: Whatever specific problem it is, you should not use dgrijalva/jwt-go, because [this repo is no longer maintained](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#this-repository-is-no-longer-maintaned). Instead use github.com/golang-jwt/jwt